# Query to change my table to foreign key using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am in need of a help to build a query that references the primary key of my `cadastro_cliente` table. I already did with the date, but with the `cadastro_cliente`-> `meter` is not working.

[image]

The query I tried to use is:

```
ALTER TABLE medidor
ADD CONSTRAINT Fk_cadastro_cliente
Foreign KEY (Cad_geral_cli_codigo)
References Cadastro_cliente (Cad_geral_cli_codigo);
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're having then?

Comment: I'm trying to create a query that takes a foreign key from my meter table referencing its primary key. But it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a useful question. Do you get an error? What is the error?